# Новые тенденции с ударениями

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Нормально ли, что мои любимые комментаторы, прекрасно владеющие словом, грамотные и знающие иностранные языки, постоянно говорят *вклЮчит, подклЮчит, повтОрит* и т. д.? Не самые любимые могут сказать *усугУбил.* Постоянно режет слух. :( Неужели это уже стало полноценной нормой?

Comment: Артем, смотря что вы понимаете под нормой. Конечно, в своей речи комментаторы должны использовать один вариант - строго литературный. Однако в непринужденной разговорной речи такое употребление вполне корректно. Так что нормой разговорной речи вполне можно назвать.

Comment: "Однако в непринужденной разговорной речи такое употребление вполне корректно". Плохо, если так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это не нормально и нормой не стало. Это все, что тут можно ответить по существу. Вопрос, считаю, был бы вполне нормальным, если бы Вы были более конкретны или, скажем, поинтересовались причинами этого явления.

А так могу только одно добавить. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что "ваши любимые", так говорящие, действительно владеют "языком и словом".

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это вселяет оптимизм! ;) Причинами я и интересуюсь, как раз спрашивая это, затрагивая эту проблему. А чтобы быть более конкретным, мне надо повнимательнее понаблюдать за ними и позапоминать. К сожалению, если у меня накопиться конкретики, чтобы добавить сюда или вообще изменить вопрос, всё равно менять будет поздно — скорее всего никто не заметит.

Answer (score 2):

Существование двух форм ударения - распространенное  русском языке явление, и оно заслуживает скорее интереса, а не раздражения. Дело в том, что этот факт всегда имеет объективные причины - к примеру, одна из форм является новой и вытесняет старую ввиду каких-либо преимуществ. И настоящая грамотность человека состоит не в осуждении, а в понимании этого фонетического процесса.

**Вот глагол "усугубить",** и вот два словаря одного автора (2004 и 2010 г.). В 2004 году даются две формы: усугУбить и усугубИть, в 2010 году они уже меняются местами. В 2004 году автор приводит правило: **если ни одна из форм прилагательного не имеет ударного окончания, то ударение в глаголе падает на основу: сугУбый - усугУбить.** Но слово постепенно выходит из этого правила, а почему? Возможно, пользователям форма "усугубИть" кажется более удобной  (как вариант, она соотносится с привычной формой "губИть").

**Глагольные формы "звонИт и включИт"** не имеют нормативных вариантов, тем не менее они широко распространены в речи. В этом случае также интересно найти причину этого явления (к примеру, можно предположить, что форма вклЮчит таким образом различается с формами "включИть, включИл").

Comment: Так речь как раз о том, что всегда было именно *усугубИт,* а не наоборот!

Comment: У Аванесова (1987) усугубИть и допускается усугУбить, то есть колебание наблюдалось и тогда.  Тут еще дело в том, что существовал устаревший теперь глагол сугУбить, поэтому форма "усугУбить" соответствовала ему, значит, это, скорее, старшая форма. СугУбить - делать бОльшим по степени проявления. ""...луч заката сугУбит блеск твоих огней" (А.К. Толстой).

Comment: Возможно, но надо со всех сторон это рассмотреть... Кстати, *скорее* в смысле *с большей вероятностью* — не вводное слово.

Comment: Разумеется, каждое слово имеет свою историю, причем изменение ударения проследить бывает сложно, по этой теме мало информации. Иногда приходится догадываться, выдвигать собственные версии, особенно важно понять,  какая из форм является устаревающей, а какая - новой, прогрессивной. И по поводу слова СКОРЕЕ. Это именно вводное слово: скорее, скорее всего. Не вводным оно является в прямом значении: этой дорогой дойти до дома скорее (быстрее).

Comment: Посмотрите, что тут написано: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_671

Comment: Да и вы тоже посмотрите, в комментарии как раз пересказано содержание именно этой статьи. "Это, скорее (= с большей вероятностью), старшая форма". Здесь нет значения "быстрее".

Comment: Вот же: "Слово «скорее» не требует постановки знаков препинания, если в предложении подразумевается сопоставление «скорее… чем», «скорее… нежели». *Посетители походили скорее на бизнесменов. Всё это напоминало скорее глупую комедию".*

Comment: 1) "А я, скорее, даже – пострадавший". Здесь подразумевается противопоставление? 2) Из словаря: Скорее... чем; скорее... нежели, в зн. союза. 1. Больше, чем. Скорее похож на отца, чем на мать. Скорее скандинав, нежели славянин. -2. Лучше, охотнее, чем. Скорее умрёт, чем отдаст свою квартиру.  3) А если не обозначено противопоставление (только подразумевается), то это какой член предложения? В справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" такой вариант не рассматривается, и официального правила такого  еще нет.  4) Скорее и скорее всего - это уже не синонимы?

Comment: Действительно, тут не совсем очевидно, как правильно. Но может в Вашем примере "скорее" используется в смысле "точнее"?

Comment: У меня "скорее" - это "скорее всего, вероятнее всего".

Comment: Мне кажется, нельзя заменять "скорее всего" просто "скорее" для краткости. Это не одно и то же.

Comment: А почему это не одно и то же? Вводное слово "скорее" (= с наибольшей вероятностью), кажется, никто не отменял.

Comment: Я в словарях этого значения не видел.